# Dockercompose to connect wordpress SQL and nginx

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm learning docker I'm new to it so i was going through docker compose, i need help in writing dockercompose file that connects wordpress sql and nginx, each of these instances will be running on different containers so i need to network between them

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put Nginx inside a Docker Container.

Then let that Nginx container talk to a Wordpress Container and the Wordpress Container has the database on a MySQL Container.

That way you can make use of standard Docker Images taken from Docker Hub. Also, your Host does not have to have any other software than Docker and Docker-compose.

Check out "[Nginx In Docker article](https://bertcatsburg.github.io/docs/category/nginx-in-docker)" which explains it in more detail.